# How to preserve the spaces when retrieving data

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a textarea in html that gets saved to a mysql table using PHP. What the user writes in this text area could look like this

```
1. Follow this directions

    First buy some wood, then get a hammer.

2. Blah blah
```

so when it saves to the database it just saves is as it is.. the problem is when I retrieve this data it would look like this (I am putting it in a `<p> </p>`

```
1. Follow this directions First buy some wood, then get a hammer. 2. Blah blah
```

But I do not want to display it like that, I want to preserve the way the user enters it.. how can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newlines should be stored in mysql - you could wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags which will tell the browser that the text is pre-formatted. And then stop the html white space cleaning which is causing your issue

Comment: Another option is to use the style `white-space: pre`.

Comment: so if i have a text area  <textarea name="longdescription" id="txtdesc">blah blah</textarea>. I should put a <pre>  before and </pre> after it and thats it?

Comment: Pretty sure <pre> tags will not work inside a text area. I think but not sure that if you did something like printf("<textarea>%s</textarea>", dbvalue); in php once you have retrieved the value - it should work - again the newlines should be there - I dont have the setup to test at the moment so am happy to be wrong

Comment: Also checkout Michael's comment about using CSS - it may work better for you